# How can I handle 404 errors for missing resources in the same path?

Tags: api

Here's the situation... I have one endpoint that is `/v1/orders/{order_id}` that returns a JSON blob of all the necessary information about a order for a product. If the order is not found it returns a 404 error. When the order is complete the product (a simple text file) can be downloaded at `/v1/orders/{order_id}/product`. If the product has not been secured yet then that endpoint will return a 404.

It seems odd to me that if you navigated to `/v1/orders/{order_id}/product` for an invalid order ID you would also get a 404 error. That kind of makes it look like maybe the order ID is correct but the product is just not available yet.

What do you think the best approach is for having this make a bit more sense.

Comment: As a side note, there's no such thing as a blob in JSON : the only data structures defined in JSON are the object and the array. Blob might stand for Binary Long OBject in programming, which could cause some confusion.

Comment: Too late to edit, but my previous comment is wrong : there are also primitive types such as string, number and boolean. Oh, and the `Array` is an `Object`, although it has its own specific notation in JSON. The complete list can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should not return 404 if the product is **found** but not secured. You could return a custom error code, probably in the 200 or 500 range or use one of the pre-defined that you think suits you better ; for example :

- 202 Accepted

  > The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. [...]
- 204 No Content

  > The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body. [...]
- 409 Conflict

  > The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. [...]

More info in [the RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) on HTTP status codes.

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom 404 page with a message and a link back to the main product page.

ie. "Sorry, but the product or page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Click here to return to the product page"